# Non-linear thermal conductivity for thin materials

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conduction

In applications (such as building science), we often use a linear model for thermal conductivity and resistance

$$R = \frac{\Delta x}{k}$$

where $k$ is the thermal conductivity of the material in W/(K·m), and $\Delta x$ the thickness of the material (in meters), i.e. **$R$ is proportional to the thickenss of the material**.

This is a valid model for insulation materials of at least several centimeters thick.

But when $\Delta x$ is very small (a few millimeters), it seems that a purely linear model doesn't hold: having **an interface** between two different materials limitates somehow the thermal transfer, without having $R$ proportional to the thickness.

As an example, some thin insulation materials have [multiple foils](https://i.imgur.com/l95xZBm.jpg), such as 20 aluminium-looking foils. In this case, a calculation of $R$ with $\frac{\Delta x}{k}$ would make no sense and lead to a very small $R$, because $\Delta x$ is very small, only a few millimeters. On the other hand, if we want to match the measured $R$ with this formula, this would imply a very small $k$ thermal conductivity - which is not true when the thickness increases. Thus a linear model (with proportionality in regards to the thickness) here doesn't apply anymore.

**Question: which model can we use to describe the thermal resistance made by the interface of multiple thin materials?** (for which $R= \Delta x / k$ doesn't apply).

---

Note: Example: if we always use $R = \Delta x / k$ we have:

- R = 0.10 / 0.035 = 2.85 for 10 cm of fiberglass, ok
- R = 0.002 / 0.05 = 0.04 for a 2-millimeter thick wall carpeting (which perceptively improves insulation), because, for wool, k = 0.05

This makes no sense - a 2-mm-thick wall carpet does really better than R = 0.04 (which is 70 times worse than the 10-cm-fiberglass R=2.85)! There surely is some other non-linear model, when there is an "interface" between two materials. The simple fact of having a material in contact with another material with another k coefficient, surely limits the thermal conduction, is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

The formula for heat conduction is also correct for thin sheets.

The thin metal sheets have two functions:

1. reflecting back thermal radiation (and thereby preventing heat loss due to another mechanism than thermal conduction).
2. inhibiting convection (and thereby preventing heat loss by another mechanism than heat conduction).

The second point is less relevant in the kind of material you show, where the foam already prevents the convection, but there are, for example, light air mattresses that use thin sheets of metal coated foil for that purpose.

The point in both cases is to use the low thermal conductivity of air as an insulator. However, air has one problem as insulating medium – it does not only conduct heat, it also shows heat transport by convection (air is heated on the warm parts and this, together with gravity creates air flows that transport the heat much better than conduction could). By adding sheets of foil, or trapping the air in a foam you suppress heat transport by convection and thus get a good heat insulator.

(Note, that [it is common to model the heat transfer between a fluid and a solid with a heat transfer coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer_coefficient) that is equivalent to some heat resistance for the surface, but this is just a simplified model of the complex convection processes).

**Addendum**

As the answer by @Puk says, there are thermal boundary resistances even between perfectly even surfaces of different solids. However, you need a lot of boundaries for those to matter, *and* the layers would have to be pressed together well for a good fit and have very even surfaces (otherwise, you have two boundaries: solid-air-solid and heat transport through the layer of air in addition to the thermal contact).

For non-perfect contact the boundary can be modelled by a [thermal contact resitance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_contact_conductance). But this is just simplified modelling of the complex heat transport with incomplete contact at the boundary, not a fundamental difference of heat conduction in thin layers!

Let's have a look at the numbers to see when those effects matter:

- The thermal contact resistance is in the range of $0.000005\,\mathrm{m^2 K / W}$ to $0.0005\,\mathrm{m^2 K/W}$ according to Wikipedia, so still at least two orders of magnitude smaller than the heat conductance of your example of a wall carpet! (and this is an effect of imperfect contact – so just an approximate model for the real process of heat conduction through an imperfect surface fit)
- The effect between solids is multiple order of magnitudes smaller again, [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfacial_thermal_resistance#Notable_room_temperature_thermal_conductance): "The lowest room temperature thermal conductance measurement to date is the Bi/Hydrogen-terminated diamond with a thermal conductance of $8.5\,\mathrm{MW m^{-2} K^{-1}}$." This is a resistance of $0.00000011\,\mathrm{m^2 K / W}$, so your layers have to be below $1\,\mathrm{\mu m}$ for this to matter compared to the bulk resistances (and this is for the material with the weakest contact, for others they are orders of magnitudes lower!).
- Finally, the heat conduction law *does* break down for very thin layers (at low temperatures), namely when the width of the layer gets comes into the range of the scattering length of the phonons – then you have so called ballistic heat transfer, instead of it being described by a diffusion equation. However, this regime is not reachable at room temperature in normal materials (basically, because they have to many temperature independent scatterers like impurities, crystal defects, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you sure the formula for heat condution really applies for thin materials? Example: a 2 millimeters thick wall carpeting. It perceptively improves insulation. But for wool, k = 0.05. Thus R = 0.002 / 0.05 = 0.04, and this makes no sense! (Compare with R = 0.10 / 0.035 = 2.85 for 10 cm of fiberglass). There surely is some other non-linear model, when there is an "interface" between two materials. The simple fact of having a material in contact with another material with another k coefficient, it surely limits the thermal conduction.

Comment: No, as I explain there are effects on convection (certainly the case for the wool wall carpeting) and possibly heat radiation. Also, the insulation properties of an inhomogeneous material using trapped air like wool will change depending on how dense it is packed, and obviously change once you are close to the structure size.

Comment: In the case of 2mm-wool wall carpeting, I don't think the radiation aspect is important (this is negligible) and convection does not seem to be impacted, I really thought the interface wool/plaster (or wool/drywall) limits the heat conduction, but much more than R = 0.002 / 0.05 = 0.04 which is nothing. (See the edit in my question).

Comment: Yes radiation is probably not important there, but it will affect convection strongly. Because it inhibits the airflow close to the wall, where the air can make direct contact with the cold wall. So instead the free convection is only driven by the not quite so cold temperature above the carpet, to add the surface of the carpet is rough, so the circulation close to the wall will be weaker. The circulation will be weaker as the temperature difference will be smaller (so the difference in specific gravity will be smaller between the warm and the cool air).

Answer (score 1):

Since the thermal contact between dissimilar materials is not perfect, their interface is often modeled by a [lumped thermal resistance per unit area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfacial_thermal_resistance), with units $\text{Km}^2/\text{W}$. Common names for it are thermal boundary resistance, thermal interface resistance, interfacial thermal resistance and Kapitza resistance. Sometimes its reciprocal is reported, called thermal boundary conductance. If the layer in question is thin or contains many interfaces, the thermal resistances of the various interfaces (including the outer interfaces that can depend on the test setup) could be important and should be included in the total thermal resistance.

Thermal boundary resistance of an interface is most reliably determined experimentally. There are certain models that attempt to predict it, of which acoustic mismatch model and diffuse mismatch model are the best known for solid-solid interfaces. These sometimes come close for more regular solids, but I don't know if they are any good for the interfaces involving insulation materials. The relatively "sparse" interface between a carpet and a wall could conceivably be quite thermally resistive, especially if there is no force pressing the carpet onto the wall.